# Calling Twitter API results in "Timestamp out of bounds" Error

Tags: twitter, oauth, postman, twitter-oauth

I am calling Twitter for fetching user Timeline Details. Here is my code

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"XXXXXXX\",oauth_token=\"XXXXXXX\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"XXXXXXX\",oauth_nonce=\"XXXXXXXX\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"XXXXXXX\"",
      "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

I am able to fetch details. But after a day I am getting this response

> {"errors":[{"code":135,"message":"Timestamp out of bounds."}]}

Is my Token getting expired ? I want to run this code as a background request.

Comment: This problem generally because of timestamp , what you set for oauth_timestamp

Comment: I was using Post Man which generated current timestamp i.e 1521786006

Answer (score 0):

The oauth_timestamp should be the number of whole seconds since 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

> {"errors":[{"code":135,"message":"Timestamp out of bounds."}]}

Usually means that your server / machine time is off by more than 30 seconds (actual time not including time-zone differences). Look at the response header to see what Twitter's time is.

oauth_timestamp=1521786006

Comment: My server time is synched & is displaying correct time. In the Response header GMT time is what it has to be. Am I missing something ?